# Which websites stock good quality free fonts?

Tags: font

I know [www.fontsquirrel.com](http://www.fontsquirrel.com) and [www.fontfabric.com](http://www.fontfabric.com) that stock free fonts, but are there any other sites out there that have good quality free fonts?

Comment: While this question can be asked here, I think it's more appropriate on [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) where you'll find better answers, including this one: [What are good sources for Open-Source fonts?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/280/what-are-good-sources-for-open-source-fonts)

Comment: Okay, just thought it may be a good reference for other users. Would it be appropriate to make it a community wiki?

Comment: Other users would be best helped by the question on Graphic Design too, I think.

Answer (score 3):

[www.dafont.com](http://dafont.com)

> body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 14

^ Poor UI. Doesn't encourage better prose - just encourages me to write filler text to meet the 30 character requirement.

Comment: Reg. 30 chars: Well, you could have used the filler to provide a little info on the resource behind the link, e.g., "14,000+ fonts, categorized, character maps, and custom previews."

Comment: @jensgram: exactly! answers that only provide a link are deemed low quality as they really do not add anything to this site and are very susceptable to link rot.

Comment: I love those creative workarounds, tho. :)

Comment: :) 12 more to go...

Comment: I would have explained my solution, but Steve Krug would have killed me for saying "Come to Dafont for excellent fonts. Come on, guys, it's free and high quality! This is the best!"